# google Authentication with vue3.js

Tags: web-applications, vuejs3, google-oauth, google-authenticator, google-auth-library

**Details**
:
"You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that is deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."

**Error**:

> idpiframe_initialization_failed

How can I solve this in vue3js. I have read the guide from the URL above and I still didn't understand.

Here are my import and my configuration

```
import GAuth from 'vue3-google-oauth2';

const app = createApp(App)
const gAuthOptions = {
 clientId: '117749311075-f3fg4d1g72ggn8ar2nip4pvf2coglif2.apps.googleusercontent.com',
 scope: 'email',
 prompt: 'consent',
 fetch_basic_profile: false
}
app.use(GAuth, gAuthOptions)
```